# How to implement a per item, fixed price for a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, price

Imagine that I am building a smart contract which simulates a lottery. I would like people to enter the lottery by buying a ticket (i.e. they would send in a certain amount of ether when they call a specific function on my contract).

Can I implement the purchase functionality so that a ticket *always* costs the equivalent of $2 USD? This doesn't seem straightforward given that the value of ether is constantly changing.

Wanting to have something cost a set price seems like it would occur frequently so I'm wondering if there is a standard way to implement it.

Note: I am just starting out with Ethereum/Solidity so I apologize if this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USD/ETH price is not intrinsically available on the blockchain. Therefore you need services such as [Oraclize for pulling price feeds to your contract](https://hackernoon.com/external-price-feeds-in-ethlend-using-oraclize-20e0b41d0b73). Specifically, you could use the [Kraken ticker API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-ticker-info) and use a simple [Oraclize query](https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start-simple-query) to integrate that data into your contract. Beware that this is significantly more complicated than just hard-coding one rate, you might want to take into consideration edge cases such as Oraclize not sending a price update in time etc.